# Error Catching Newline in Lex

Tags: lex

I have been debugging for a couple of days now and can't seem to fix this bug. The following code is a Lex file for C language grammar.

I have two problems I haven't been able to spot yet.

This first is newline detection. It seems to leave the newline char in the output and doesn't increment the line var (to keep track of line, column for error feedback).

I have every combination of newline escape sequence but can't seem catch it.

The second is detecting a single quote followed by a newline, which should produce an
illegal character error.

What am I not seeing? Thanks in advance!

```
%{
int col = 1;
int line = 1;
int aux_col = 0;
int err = 0; 
%}

%x C_COMMENT

 /* Identifiers */
ids    [a-zA-Z_]([a-zA-Z0-9_])*
 /* Integers    */
inteiros    0|[1-9]([0-9])*

 /* Chars or any Escape Sequence */
chrlit    (\'[^\n\'\\]?\')|(\'\\.\')
 /* Strings */  
strlit    (\"[^\n\"\\]?+\")         

 /* Char Error: Multi Char Constant */
chr_multi    (\'[^\n\']{2,}\')

 /* Char Error: Non-terminated Char Constant */
chr_nonterm    (\'[^\n\']{1,})

 /* String Error: Non-terminated String Constant */
strerr    (\"[^\n\"]?+)



%%

"/*"    {BEGIN(C_COMMENT); if(col==0) {aux_col=3;} else {aux_col=2;}}
<C_COMMENT>"*/"    {col+=aux_col+2; aux_col=0; BEGIN(INITIAL);}
<C_COMMENT><<EOF>>    {printf("Line %d, col %d: unterminated comment\n",line, col); BEGIN(INITIAL);}
<C_COMMENT>.    {aux_col++;}


"do"|"struct"|"auto"|"long"|"switch"|"break"|"enum"|"register"|"typedef"
"case"|"extern"|"union"|"float"|"short"|"unsigned"|"const"|"for"|"signed"       "void"|"continue"|"goto"|"sizeof"|"volatile"|"default"|"static"
{col+=yyleng; printf("RESERVED\n");}

return    {col+=yyleng; printf("RETURN\n");}

while    {col+=yyleng; printf("WHILE\n");}

printf    {col+=yyleng; printf("PRINTF\n");}

atoi    {col+=yyleng; printf("ATOI\n");}

if    {col+=yyleng; printf("IF\n");}

int    {col+=yyleng; printf("INT\n");}

itoa    {col+=yyleng; printf("ITOA\n");}

char    {col+=yyleng; printf("CHAR\n");}

"&&"    {col+=yyleng; printf("AND\n");}

"&"    {col+=yyleng;  printf("AMP\n");}

"="    {col+=yyleng;  printf("ASSIGN\n");}

"*"    {col+=yyleng; printf("AST\n");}

","    {col+=yyleng; printf("COMMA\n");}

"/"    {col+=yyleng; printf("DIV\n");}

"=="    {col+=yyleng; printf("EQ\n");}

">="    {col+=yyleng; printf("GE\n");}

">"    {col+=yyleng; printf("GT\n");}

"{"    {col+=yyleng; printf("LBRACE\n");}

"<="    {col+=yyleng; printf("LE\n");}

"("    {col+=yyleng; printf("LPAR\n");}

"["    {col+=yyleng; printf("LSQ\n");}

"<"    {col+=yyleng; printf("LT\n");}

"-"    {col+=yyleng; printf("MINUS\n");}

"%"    {col+=yyleng; printf("MOD\n");}

"!="    {col+=yyleng; printf("NE\n");}

"!"    {col+=yyleng; printf("NOT\n");}

"+"    {col+=yyleng; printf("PLUS\n");}

"}"    {col+=yyleng; printf("RBRACE\n");}

")"    {col+=yyleng; printf("RPAR\n");}

"]"    {col+=yyleng; printf("RSQ\n");}

";"    {col+=yyleng; printf("SEMI\n");}

\|\|    {col+=yyleng; printf("OR\n");}



{ids}    {col+=yyleng; printf("ID(%s)\n",yytext);}
{inteiros}    {col+=yyleng; printf("INTLIT(%s)\n", yytext);}
{strlit}    {col+=yyleng; printf("STRLIT(%s)\n", yytext);}
{chrlit}    {col+=yyleng; printf("CHRLIT(%s)\n", yytext);}


{chr_multi}    {if(col==0) {col++;err=1;}
            printf("Line %d, col %d: multi-character char constant\n", line, col);
            col+=yyleng;
            if(err == 1) {col--;err=0;}}

{chr_nonterm}    {if(col==0) {col++;err=1;}
            printf("Line %d, col %d: unterminated char constant\n", line, col);
            col+=yyleng;if(err == 1) {col--;err=0;}}

{strerr}    {if(col==0) {col++;err=1;}
            printf("Line %d, col %d: unterminated string constant\n", line,col);
            col+=yyleng;
            if(err == 1) {col--;err=0;}}

" "    {col++;};
'\n'    {col=1;line++;printf("BAR N\n");}
"\\n"    {col=1;line++;printf("BAR N2\n");}
\n    {col=1;line++;printf("BAR N3\n");}

.|\'    {printf("Line %d, col %d: illegal character ('%s')\n", line, col, yytext); col++;}

%%

int main () {
    yylex();
    return 0;
}

int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time!

I piped a file into the program. For example just a keyword followed by two enter's.

if<enter>
<enter>

Comment: PS. Yes I fixed the ' bug just by adding | and joining the three lines. Plus I fixed the COMMENT state to catch \n. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not matching newlines in comments. `.` matches any character **but** newline.

After fixing the rule to match keywords (adding a couple of `|` and putting it all on one line) the program **did** report an illegal character on a single quote followed by a newline. So please give the exact input that give unexpected results.

Best regards from a fellow Bryan.